# AWS LexRuntimeV2 Credentials with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I'm working on a cloud bot project using NodeJS. I have to run AmazonLex2 instances so have done a npm install @aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2.

I believe we have to add our credentials as a Runtime constructor, now before we run the application?

```
const { LexRuntimeV2 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2');

class AmazonLexV2 {
    constructor(credentials) {
        this.botName = credentials.bot_name;
        this.alias = credentials.bot_alias;
        this.apiVersion = credentials.apiVersion;
        this.region = credentials.region;

    this.lexruntime = new LexRuntimeV2({
        correctClockSkew: true,
        apiVersion:  credentials.apiVersion,
        region: credentials.region,
        accessKeyId: credentials.access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: credentials.secret_access_key
    });
}
```

....

I keep getting this error:

```
{
   "mensaje": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
   "status": 403,
   "data": ""
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement AWS-SDK Lex2 for nodejs, you have to do:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { LexRuntimeV2 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2');

this.lexruntime = new LexRuntimeV2({
        apiVersions: '2020-08-07',
        correctClockSkew: true,
        region: credentials.region,
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
            accessKeyId: credentials.access_key_id, 
            secretAccessKey: credentials.secret_access_key, 
        })
})
```